# Prevent navigation page with unsave data on web resource Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

It's possible to prevent the navigation to another entities or anywhere, if I have unsave data on Dynamics HTML CRM web resoure file?

Actually I'm validate when the user press back on the history button, but when clic on another action on CRM window, I lost the unsave data on my form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? what exactly your requirements are? where is your webresource? on a FORM?

Comment: Yes, my web resource is in a form on the opportunity entity, the user can edit values in the fields of web resource, but when he click in some Lookup in the CRM form (not in my web resource), CRM only open the form of the related entity and the user loses the information that was edited in the web resource. This is what I want to avoid, prevent to the user to lose the information and ask if want continue or keep the value of the web resource fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through unsupported (**window.onbeforeunload**) code as:

Write a function (with in your webresource) responsible to check that the web resource is dirty or not?

```
function isMyWebResourceIsDirty()
{
}
```

Expose this function through **Xrm** object so the whole page can have access to this function as (this code be within your web resource):

```
Xrm.fnIsMyWebResourceIsDirty = isMyWebResourceIsDirty;
```

This code should trigger on form load (this code should be on your main Form)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      if(Xrm.fnIsMyWebResourceIsDirty()){
      alert('Save the changes first...');
      return;
      }
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.